The filename is not recognised as an OLE file
I have this code but for some reason i can't read the xls correctly..
The path is correct but i have got this error..
Someone can help me?
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CTTFileProcessor extends Controller
{
    public function process(Request $request)
    {
        //$file = Storage::disk('public')->path('Discriminativo.xls');
        $filePath = str_replace('\\', '/', Storage::disk('public')->path('Discriminativo.xls'));
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
        $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filePath);
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $data = $worksheet->toArray();
        dd($data);
        exit;
    }
}


Although old, this seems relevant. You are using Reader\Xls and maybe the file is an xlsx file?
